# winston-daily-rotate-file creates a new file when current file has not extended it's maxsize

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I would like to only create a new file, when current file extends it's maxSize.
However it seems like when the `%DATE%` no longer applies to the current(meaning that the current date is different from the one when created), it will create a new file instead of using the current file.

for example:

if I create a file
`application-2019-07-19T05-12.log`
and the wait a few minutes it will create a new file, with the current time(`application-2019-07-19T05-15.log`) even though the first file is not full.

Config:

```
            level: 'info',
            filename: 'logs/application-%DATE%.log',
            datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH-mm',
            maxsize: 1k, // for testing
            maxFiles: 3,
            audit: "logs/application-audit.json"
```

Is this the expected behavior or could my configs be wrong?

Another solution to my problem would be if I could get rid of %DATE% from the file name. however the default pattern is `winston.log.%DATE%` and I have tried setting the `datePattern` to `'', undefined, log` etc. without success.